# Matrix Similarity Proof (Show Matrix $B$ Nonsingular)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that if A is similar to $B$ and $A$ is nonsingular, then $B$ must
>   also be nonsingular and $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are similar:

Work:

$A=S^{-1}BS$

$A^{-1}=(S^{-1}BS)^{-1}$

$A^{-1}=S^{-1}B^{-1}(S^{-1})^{-1}$

$A^{-1}=S^{-1}B^{-1}S$

I can prove that $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are similar, but **I am unsure of how to show $B$ that is nonsingular.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A=S^{-1}BS\iff SAS^{-1}=B$$

Now multiply both sides of the identity with $SA^{-1}S^{-1}$

$$SA^{-1}S^{-1}SAS^{-1}=I=\left(SA^{-1}S^{-1}\right)B$$
$$SAS^{-1}SA^{-1}S^{-1}=I=B\left(SA^{-1}S^{-1}\right)$$

And we have found $C=SA^{-1}S^{-1}$ such that $BC=CB=I$

Comment: So we can find $SA^{-1}S^{-1}$ just by eyeballing it?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I guess we can apply each matrix one at a time, step by step

Comment: You got we multiply by the matrices one by one to get to $I$

Answer (score 0):

$$
A=S^{-1}BS \iff B=SAS^{-1}
$$
And the product of nonsingular matrices is nonsingular.

Answer (score 0):

Overkill:
$$ 0 \neq \det(A) = \det(S^{-1}BS) = \det(S^{-1}) \det(B) \det(S) $$
So $\det(B) \neq 0$.